# Package structure should be same as directory structure in Java "always"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Package structure should be same as directory structure in Java it seems in Eclipse.
I tried to browse through the formal documentation on Oracle Java docs but nowhere I could find this rule

Does this rule extend to other IDEs such as Netbeans or is this a rule of Java language itself?
How strict is this rule, can it be deviated from and why was it made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's specified in the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html) as a rule that compilers *may* require:

> Packages that are stored in a file system may have certain constraints on the organization of their compilation units to allow a simple implementation to find classes easily.

For example, if you specify all the source filenames on the command line for javac, you don't *have* to follow those rules... but it's pretty much *universally* used, and I wouldn't dream of violating this rule for anything other than tiny tests.

Note that by default, javac will generate the class file as a peer of the source file, regardless of package structure; if you specify `-d` it will generate the appropriate output structure even if it doesn't match the source structure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to have a look at [a good tutorial about packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html). The first sentence of the link:

> *Many implementations of the Java platform rely on hierarchical file systems to manage source and class files, although The Java Language Specification does not require this.*

Answer (score 1):

Its not a IDE specific. Directory structure and package structure should match each other. You can find more details in Java Specification and Certification books.

Comment: Some of the other posts mention that the Java Language specification does not require this.

Comment: Yes. I said it **should** (not must) match.

Comment: That "may" in JLS is there as an attempt to not prevent some kind of a custom system for managing .java and .class files. For instance, in the really old days, Visual Age for Java stored project files in a database of sorts. All modern Java compilers, JREs and IDEs require folder structure to match package structure. The only exception that I am aware of is invoking javac against a specific .java file (as opposed to a folder containing a bunch of .java files). Not useful for anything outside of quick experimentation.

Comment: Source files(`.java`) don't need to match with package structure. *Class files* (`.class`) should match.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can have following code, without putting it inside `my/app` folder

```
package my.app;

public class Tmp{

}
```

and compile this without errors from command prompt.

But for running the application, the class files needs to be in respect folders mentioned in package.

As Jon Skeet mentions its more for organization purposes so that run time can resolve if there are conflicting class names.