# Configuring IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, setup-project

My problem is very simple to describe.

I've made a Class named Car and I let IntelliJ build the Car.class file.

After that I've made another Project which has a dummy class called Main which wrapps this Car object.
In the project structure I've added as an external library the folder which contains Car.class.

So basicly after declaring the Car member variable in my Main dummy class, IntellJ normaly suggests me to import Car which is shown in the picture below.

### Picture1

[image]

When I choose to import Car class it directly writes down the package before the Class name (not the usual import statement) and the import fails as shown on this picture.

### Picture2

(note: the reason it states org.dino.test.pojos is because Car class package is org.dino.test.pojos)
[image]

The project setup is shown below.

### Picture 3

[image]

Does someone know how to setup this project structure so such things work?

Comment: The double-org is suspicious.

Comment: Hi the first org is just the name of the Library

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi, I've edited the picture so its more obvious.

Comment: In the first picture your library has the Car class in `org.test` and the second on in `org.dino.test`. Please clarify your current setup

Answer (score -1):

The fact that IntelliJ has marked the `org` directory as the library home is suspicious- I suspect that you have defined the classes in the library as the `org` subdirectory rather than the JAR or classes directory itself.

You also have a folder structure that is inconsistent with your package structure.

When you define the library, select the `testLibrary` directory/JAR rather than one of the directories inside it. Also, ensure that the folder structure inside your library matches the Java package of the class within it.

Comment: Noup that doesn't matter. Try one case for yourself. Make a class, build it. Copy the respective class file into a folder and try to reference it in another project.

Comment: When you copy the class into a folder in the library, are you ensuring that the folder matches the package of that class?

Comment: No I'm not. The point is I also don't want to do it this way.

Comment: Ah! In which case, that's a different question. See the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416017/package-structure-should-be-same-as-directory-structure-in-java-always.